# Binding an Eloquent model to the service container

Tags: php, laravel

Has anyone used the IoC container to bind to an Eloquent Model?

For example, I have a repository for my Account and Category eloquent models. The Account model has a hasMany relationship with Categories. The Category repository has the Account repository injected into the constructor.

Instead, I would like to inject an actual Account model like this...

In my service provider:

```
$this->app->bind(App\Models\Account::class, function ($app) {
    return (Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->account : null;
});
```

In my repository

```
use App\Models\Account;

class CategoryRepository
{
    private $account;

    public function __construct(Account $account = null)
    {
        // check and throw error if null
        $this->account = $account;
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->account->categories()->get();
    }
}
```

Is it bad practice, or what foreseeable pitfalls would I fall into, if I bind an actual eloquent model to the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

While you could do this, you probably don't want to. If you did this, the IoC container would always use that binding to resolve the Accounts, which is not what you're looking for.

The more appropriate way to go would be to define a binding for how to resolve the CategoryRepository, instead of the Account. That way, in the code to resolve the CategoryRepository, you can make sure that the actual account is always passed in, or null if not available.

```
$this->app->bind(App\Repos\CategoryRepository::class, function ($app) {
    $account = Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->account : null;
    return new App\Repos\CategoryRepository($account);
});
```